# If $a_n > 0$ prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1)}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have an interesting task: If $a_n > 0$, prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1)}$$ converges.

I thought that it will be simple because ratio test gives me:
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}= \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}+1}\cdot a_n^{-1} < 1 \cdot a_n^{-1} = \frac{1}{a_n}$$ and $a_n$ should be in $[0,1]$. But... In my opinion it can be over that... why need I assume that $ a_n \rightarrow g \in [0,1] $?
There is similar topic on this forum, but It was not solved there...

 @edit
I saw that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)} = 1-\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_N)} < 1 $$
So if series of partial sum is bounded from up, the sum converges, that is right?
@edit2 but It is good? Look at that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n+1-1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n-1})}-\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)} $$ why somebody changed first part into $1$?
@edit3 Ok, I think that I have understood, thanks for your time ;)

Comment: You shouldn't be using the ratio test at all.

Comment: I suppose you must assume $a_0=0$.

Comment: It is not finished there

Comment: @user10354138 I know, but there it should works too

Comment: @VirtualUser: Since sequence of partial sums are monotonic and bounded (from above), so the partial sums converge to the supremum as a consequence of Monotone convergence theorem. Hence the summation converges to the supremum.

Comment: God, It is not duplicate, I just do not understand what happened in potential "orginal" post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\,} {{{a_n } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {a_n  + 1} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\,} {{{\left( {a_n  + 1} \right) - 1} \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {a_n  + 1} \right)}}}
  =  \cdots  \cr} 
$$

(continuing)

$$
\eqalign{
  &  = {{a_1 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}} + {{a_2 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)}}
 + {{a_3 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)\left( {a_3  + 1} \right)}} +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = {{a_1 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}} + {{a_2  + 1 - 1} \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)}}
 + {{a_3  + 1 - 1} \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)\left( {a_3  + 1} \right)}} +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = {{a_1 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}} + {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}} - {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)}}
 + {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)}} - {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)\left( {a_3  + 1} \right)}} +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = {{a_1 } \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}} + {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)}}
 - {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)\left( {a_3  + 1} \right)}} +  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 - {1 \over {\left( {a_1  + 1} \right)\left( {a_2  + 1} \right)\left( {a_3  + 1} \right)}} +  \cdots  =  \cdots  \cr} 
$$

Comment: I used your hint to solve my problem, can you check if I done this well?

Comment: yes, you got the idea (it's a telescoping sum), **but** you shall pay attention to the *starting point* (there is not an $a_0$ to subtract): I continued for some further steps .. now you shall be able to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the ratio test is useless because you have zero information on $a_n$.

May I suggest that you compute the first partial sums to “get a feeling” about what happens?